# Messenger Platform - How to get total number of messages between users and the bot?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger

I have a chat bot based on Facebook's [Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) and it now has more than 10k users. People interact and chat with the bot everyday.
I want to retrieve **the total number of messages / conversations between users and the bot** so that I can put it on the bot's website and impress website visitors, something like this: 
[image]
Are there any API from Facebook that support retrieving that information ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve from `/<pageID>/conversations`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/